# R keeps crashing after running line library(car) or library(effects)

Tags: r

I'm currently running R 3.3.2 on my mac, which is currently running OS Sierra. I also have updated Qwartz and I'm using mran. I'm not sure if this is a problem with r studio or with r itself. I was previously running El Capitain and it wasn't working, so I updated my operating system and it's still not working. Does anyone know what I should do?

edit: I have also tried uninstalling the programs and reinstalling them, but the problem persists

Comment: Welcome to SO, in order to _"know what I should do?"_ you would be pleased to provide source code of what is crashing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean but I went to the drop down code menu and ran source and it responded with souce('~/.active-rstudio-document')

Comment: I have the same issue for this combination. After reinstall remains crashing. It is not RStudio. If you start MRAN, it crashes as well. Symlink points to Current -> 3.3.2-MRO as it should be under /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/